# How to push commits after clone?

Tags: git, version-control

On a backup server I have one repo. I get it via `git clone` to my home pc (development goes on work pc). After `clone` I do `git fetch` and then `git checkout dev`. In the `dev` branch I want to change the last commit comment like `git commit --amend -m 'Fixed commit'` and the push it back like `git push origin dev` but error occurs:

```
To /*****.git
 ! [rejected]        dev -> dev (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '/*********.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Where is the problem? How to get `dev` branch from the remote repo and push data to it.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to `git commit --amend` re-writing the local commit history on your `dev` branch.

If you're 100% sure that your commit will not step on anyone elses work, you can force push the branch with `git push origin dev -f`.

Another option is to `git pull`, fix any merge conflicts, create another commit with the newly merged code, and push that up. This is generally considered a safe practice, but can pollute your commit history a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the remote branch is ahead of your own, meaning it has at least one commit you do not have. Try a git pull then merge any changes and push again.